# HTML5 javascript libraries

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for javascript libraries that helps with HTML5 development.

Please only post one library per answer, and don't forget to describe it.

Comment: This should be marked Community Wiki since there's no definitive answer. Edit your post and tick the `Community Wiki` checkbox.

Answer (score 10):

[Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) is the best way to detect which HTML5 features a browser supports.

Answer (score 8):

"[Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) is an open programming language for people who want to program images, animation, and interactions for the web without using Flash or Java applets. Processing.js uses Javascript to draw shapes and manipulate images on the HTML5 Canvas element. The code is light-weight, simple to learn and makes an ideal tool for visualizing data, creating user-interfaces and developing web-based games."

Comment: I don't think that Processing is what the OP was looking for, but it's a nice reference.

Comment: Actually I think it is. In any case the polls are open ;)

Comment: @Pointy: the answerer **is** the OP, note the blue box ;)

Comment: Oh you're right!!!  Well I'm dumb I guess.  Still my point was that there's more to HTML5 than the "canvas" tag!!

Answer (score 3):

[Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) — Raphaël’s goal is to provide an adapter that will make drawing vector art compatible cross-browser and easy.

Answer (score 3):

I'll post about Easel.js and it's sibils hoho. They're from the same developer [GSkinner](http://gskinner.com/) I post all related libraries because of this. I've just used Easel a little, but the others seem promising. I post the URL and their description:

[Easel.js](http://easeljs.com/)

> The new Canvas element in HTML5 is powerful, but it can be difficult to work with. It has no internal concept of discrete display elements, so you are required to manage updates manually. The Easel Javascript library provides a retained graphics mode for canvas including a full, hierarchical display list, a core interaction model, and helper classes to make working with Canvas much easier.

It supports [TweenJS](http://tweenjs.com/)

> TweenJS provides an extremely simple API for creating complex sequenced animations in Javascript. It includes basic (experimental) support for working with style sheets.

Also supports [SoundJS](http://soundjs.com/)

> Audio in HTML is promising, but can be quite difficult to work with. Each browser has a similar but different approach, which requires a lot of guess and test, and edge cases, which can add up to a lot of time spent. The SoundJS JavaScript library provides a simple API, and some powerful features to make working with audio a breeze.

And [Zoë](http://easeljs.com/zoe.html)

> Zoë (from Zoetrope) is an open source application for OSX or Windows which provides an easy way to export Flash animations as sprite sheets for use with EaselJS and HTML5.
>   Simply drag a SWF file onto the application. It will scan the main timeline to find frame labels and dimensions. You can tweak the frame bounds, edit settings, then export a sprite sheet image and EaselJS code defining a SpriteSheet instance with frame data based on the timeline labels.
>   SWFs should have all animation on the main timeline, with frame labels to indicate the start of animations. Nested graphics are fine.

I haven't used them all but seem quite interesting =)

Answer (score 2):

> [html5sql](http://html5sql.com/) is a light JavaScript module that makes working with the HTML5 Web Database a whole lot easier. Its primary function is to provides a structure for the **sequential** processing of SQL statements within a single transaction.

Answer (score 1):

The only one I have found is [html5widgets](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/07/27/cross-browser-html5-forms-using-modernizr-webforms2-and-html5widgets/).

I would have assumed that there where several competing libraries for this.

But it does implement most of the new html 5 form goodness, which is what I care about...

Answer (score 1):

Check out RGraph.

Available at http://www.rgraph.net/

Complete set of graphs for html5.

Free for non-commercial use, else it is 49 Pounds (English)

Answer (score 1):

I use [Perkins HTML5+CSS3 framework](http://p.erkins.com/) "He" describes himself as following:

> I am a Framework thought to make the life of designers and developers a bit easier. I use the latest Web standards, also known as HTML5 and CSS3. To take more advantage and allow you not to repeat yourself, I am based in LESS.js, which means that you can forget some of the proprietary browser prefixes. Also, I carry a number of preloaded basic styles, mixins, helpers, transparent textures and a @font-face driven icon set. If HTML is your passion, I can help you to make wireframes quickly using the dynamic grid, based in Tyler Tate's 1kb CSS Grid which is already included and can be configured in the perkins.config.less file, as well as many other options.

Answer (score 1):

CreateJS is a good collection of HTML5 library.

http://www.createjs.com

Answer (score 0):

While more than a javascript library [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) looks really usefull.

"HTML5 Boilerplate is the professional badass's base HTML/CSS/JS template for a fast, robust and future-proof site."

Answer (score 0):

[ExplorerCanvas](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/) — Modern browsers like Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera support the HTML5 canvas tag to allow 2D command-based drawing. ExplorerCanvas brings the same functionality to Internet Explorer. To use, web developers only need to include a single script tag in their existing web pages.

Answer (score 0):

[RoCanvas.js](http://re.trotoys.com/article/rocanvas/)

Creates interactive drawing board that lets users draw on your site (can be useful for avatars, or much better for colaborative projects, learning etc